# How to add A selected parameters in Report Preview and excel export in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008-r2, msbi

i have created the ssrs report with parameters.
Whatever parameters i am selecting in the dropdown i want to show that in Report Preview and excel export.

Can anyone please guide how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use textboxes and enter the parameters in the expression. For single-value parameters, use either

```
=Parameters!ReportParameter1.Label
```

or

```
=Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value
```

Parameters have a label and a value. For example you can have a user with User_Id (value) = `1` and Username (label) = `Rajashri`. So you use the appropriate one.

If you have multi-value parameters, you will need to use the Join function in order to turn them into a list.

Example :

```
=Join(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Label, ", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

To show this information on Export, you’ll need to include it in your report somewhere.

The approach we have taken is to display this information at the bottom of the table (for example), by merging all the cells and listing the parameters used for the report

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jonnus !This solved my basic queries.I am populating the child teams  based on the parent teams.Child team values i am taking from my CTE query and not from parameter.In this case how can i populate the child team names?

Comment: Is this cte query part of the dataset you are reporting on or a separate dataset?

Comment: the cte query is part of dataset. I am embedding cte query in the dataset